# Calling a method within Twig

Tags: twig, symfony-2.1

I have a class called Plans.  There are two methods that I'm working with: indexAction() deletePlan($id).  The indexAction() renders index.html.twig with the following content:

**index.html.twig**

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.description}}</td>
  <td><a href="">Delete</td>
</tr>
```

For the Delete link in the last  tag, I need to actually execute the deletePlan($id) method.  I do not want this to be an actual page that is redirected to.  I plan to call the deletePlan($id) method, capture if it returns true or false, and then hide the  (row) using AJAX.

So the question is:  Can I call the deletePlan($id) method inside my twig file without actually having a page setup, a route set up, and renaming the method to deletePlanAction($id)?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Anything you want accessible over HTTP should have a route and a controller. You can just add a new action and have it call your `deletePlan`, then return a response with som kind of satus of the operation, JSON presumably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply call a method from a template. You need to create an action that handles the request. You can use the route of this action in your AJAX call. Besides you need to pass `id`. Set up a JavaScript that executes the AJAX call on a click on the `<a>`-tag.

Using jQuery the AJAX part could look like this:

```
$.post('{{ path('routeNameOfDeleteAction') }}', function(data) {
    $('someSelector').html(data);
});
```

If you want this to work only using AJAX you can add this in your delete action:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('routeNameOfIndexAction'));
}
```

Finally your controller can return a response in JSON that holds the result like `true` or `false`.

Comment: You can use `$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()` as well to check it ;)